# JQuery: has no method 'cookie'

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, websocket

I've got a SPA application based on websockets. This application log out user each time he press F5 button. I want to prevent such behaviour, and as one said "don't piss off my user each time the'll press F5".

***what I'm trying:*** I'm trying to save websocket to cookies on `join` method (see code below)

***Problem:*** JQuery says me that there is no cookie when `join` method is calling:

```
TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
} has no method 'cookie'
```

***Question:*** what should I do

***Code:***

```
var le = {
    ws: null,

    join: function () {
        if (!$.cookie('ws')) { //HERE PROBLEM COMES!!!
            var location = document.location.toString().replace('https://', 'wss://')/* + 'levirs'*/;
            this.ws = new WebSocket(location);
            this.ws.onopen = this.onOpen;
            this.ws.onmessage = this.onMessage;
            this.ws.onclose = this.onClose;
            this.ws.onerror = this.onError;
            $.cookie('ws', this.ws, {expires: 1});
        } else {
            this.ws = $.cookie('ws');
        }
    },

    //another methods
}
```

Comment: you need to include the cookie plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: remove the { expires: 1}, I had the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the [jQuery Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) for that to work.